# Code repeating itself infinitively for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to make an extension that shows information in the popup. It gets this information by making a GET request to a URL which I get by looking at a request from a certain web page. To test, I just print the body of the request.

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
    logURL,
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}
);

function logURL(details) {
    var url = details.url;
    if (url.startsWith('https://www.whatever.com/api/')) {
        httpGet(url);
    }
}

function httpGet(apiURL) {   
    let data;
    function setData(dt) {
        data = dt;
    }   
    fetch(apiURL)
        .then(response => response.json()).then( json => setData(json))
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => {
            console.log("Data received 1 --> ", data);
            data = null;
    });
}
```

However, it keeps printing the body indefinitely. I don't know why. I would like to know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because any time a webrequest completes, it calls logURL, which calls httpGet and starts a new webrequest, which completes and calls logURL, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The call back `logURL` is invoked on completion of a request. This will go on forever because on completion of one request you are making another one